# How to write a json custom comparator for a specific datatype using skyscreamer (JSONAssert)?

Tags: java, junit, jackson, jsonassert

How do I write a `JSONCustomComparator` not for a specific field, but a specific datatype?

I know for a specific field, I can do,

```
CustomComparator comparator = new CustomComparator(
            JSONCompareMode.LENIENT,
            new Customization("field.nunber", (o1, o2) -> true),
            new Customization("field.code", (o1, o2) -> true));
JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJsonAsString, actualJsonAsString, comparator);
```

But how do I do it for a specific datatype? E.g. I have to compare Boolean and Int(true with 1, false with 0),

```
 ValueMatcher<Object> BOOL_MATCHER = new ValueMatcher<Object>() {
    @Override
    public boolean equal(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (o1.toString().equals("true") && o2.toString().equals("1")) {
            return true;
        } else if (o1.toString().equals("false") && o2.toString().equals("0")) {
            return true;
        } else if (o2.toString().equals("true") && o1.toString().equals("1")) {
            return true;
        } else if (o2.toString().equals("false") && o1.toString().equals("0")) {
            return true;
        }
        return JSONCompare.compareJSON(o1.toString(), o2.toString(), JSONCompareMode.LENIENT).passed();
    }
};
CustomComparator comparator = new CustomComparator(JSONCompareMode.LENIENT, new Customization("*", BOOL_COMPARATOR));
```

**But** this doesn't seem to be the best way, also the BOOL_MATCHER will only return boolean, not the JSONCompareResult, so that the `diff` can be shown.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new custom Comparator by extending the `DefaultComparator`.

```
private static class BooleanCustomComparator extends DefaultComparator {
    public BooleanCustomComparator(final JSONCompareMode mode) {
        super(mode);
    }
    @Override
    public void compareValues(String prefix, Object expectedValue, Object actualValue, JSONCompareResult result)
            throws JSONException {
        if (expectedValue instanceof Number && actualValue instanceof Boolean) {
            if (BooleanUtils.toInteger((boolean)actualValue) != ((Number) expectedValue).intValue()) {
                result.fail(prefix, expectedValue, actualValue);
            }
        } else if (expectedValue instanceof Boolean && actualValue instanceof Number) {
            if (BooleanUtils.toInteger((boolean)expectedValue) != ((Number) actualValue).intValue()) {
                result.fail(prefix, expectedValue, actualValue);
            }
        } else {
            super.compareValues(prefix, expectedValue, actualValue, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJson, actualJson, new BooleanCustomComparator(JSONCompareMode.STRICT));
```